# Border adds padding to div with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div (class="outer") with another div (class="inner") inside of it. When I add border  of 2px to the "outer" div, padding is automatically added to the outer div. It looks like 1px padding on the top, left and right and none at the bottom. How do we remove all the padding? I set `padding: 0;` for the "outer" div and it has no effect. Is this a browser bug? I am using Chrome on Windows. I even tried IE. If I change the zoom in Chrome, the padding changes too and at a certain zoom (125%), the padding becomes 0. The problem can be seen here:

https://codepen.io/overdrivemachines/pen/oNewBym

If the border is removed from the "outer" div, the outer div loses its padding.

There should be no yellow in the border, however I see yellow as shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtbFt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

there's no padding, what you're seeing is the border you just added :) Change the border color to a different color than outer's background and you can see that.

Comment: I can still see the yellow in the border. The border color is red. The background color of the outer div is red. I am not supposed to see any yellow from the outer div's background!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4fm9viS - that's what I see on my end. No yellow, just illusion of padding due to border.

Comment: Here is what I see: [https://imgur.com/a/686Pj15](https://imgur.com/a/686Pj15) The yellow is not supposed to be there in the border. The yellow in the border is from the outer div's background color.

Comment: your pic doesn't show the yellow in the border, mine does. What browser are you using? How can this be possible?

Comment: I tried Edge, Chrome & FF and none of them show what you're seeing for the code on codepen. Perhaps you have some extra css? Personally I stay away from borders unless they're absolutely necessary, the same effect can be achieved by making the outer red to begin with and giving it a padding equal to the desired "border" width.

Comment: I don't see the issue on another computer (desktop vs my laptop), however, if I zoom the browser to 110%, I am able to see the yellow in the border. I think this is bug in Chrome. How do we report bugs to Google?

Comment: zoom is unreliable and will always present artifacts especially when it comes to borders. What width should your 2px border be at 110%? The browser can't render 2.2px, so your layout will be broken and bleed trough. You'll notice that if you zoom to 150% or 200%, it will look fine since 3px & 4px can be rendered. Likewise, if you change the border width to 10px, it will render fine at 110% since 11px can be rendered.

Comment: `outline: red solid 2px;` seems to solve the issues I am facing. Even zooming doesn't cause any issues. Thank you for looking into it. Windows has a default scaling of 125% (in the display setting) for my laptop. Perhaps that's why I am facing those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a default scaling of 125% (in the display setting) for my laptop. Perhaps that's why some of you will not be able to see the yellow in the border I was referring to. If you get rid of the border property and replace it with `outline: red solid 2px;` it seems to solve the issues I am facing. With outline, even zooming chrome doesn't cause any issues. There is probably a rendering bug in Chrome and other browsers in rendering borders when the display in Windows settings is set to 125%.